# how to use auth_redirect() redirect visitor to login page if they are not login when they click account and order page?

Tags: php, functions, login

I created a drop down menu under My Account, like order, account info, address...etc, how can I just redirect all visitor to login page if they are not login?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure `auth_redirect()` is executed for the user on the desired pages (before any content is printed).

There are many ways to do this. You can add something like this to functions.php

```php
$pages_auth_check = [ 25, 40, 55 ]; // IDs of the pages to check.
$current_page     = get_the_ID();

if ( in_array( $current_page, $pages_auth_check ) ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

So the `auth_redirect()` will be executed only for the pages with the specified IDs.